lacp on two dark fiber provider with different span
We have two dark fiber connections from two different providers, Provider A and Provider B. The span for Provider A is 20 km, and the span for Provider B is 25 km. I want to know if I can use QSFP28-100G-BiDi-ER optics and create an LACP link. Is there any potential problem? Also, what hash algorithm would you suggest for this LACP, considering the spans are different?

5 km of fiber add ~24 µs[*1] of one-way latency - usually negligible and absolute usable with LAG/LACP since traffic is distributed by hash anyway.
The purpose of hashing flows is to keep each flow on a single physical connection (to avoid out-of-order delivery) while distributing the entirety of traffic as evenly as possible with a stateless algorithm.
For almost all purposes, hashing IP addresses and transport-layer ports yields the best results. Hashing only IP addresses keeps all traffic between any two endpoints on the same interface. Hashing only MAC addresses even keeps all traffic between any two hops on the same interface - so if you're routing, there's no distribution at all.
[*1] Assuming a refractive index of n=1.45, the velocity factor is .69, resulting in 4.84 µs/km latency (or 1/c0*n).

Thanks Zac, i want to add another dark fiber to my LACP and that one has 35-40KM the difference of span with my current dark fiber is 15-20KM, Do you think it will be usable ?

LACP doesn't limit the allowed skew between physical links, so as long as your workloads don't object, that extra delay won't cause a problem. However, you might want to consider using routed links between location instead of switched ones which give you more control over traffic distribution (e.g. policy routing by source, destination, protocol, DSCP, etc.).
